# Struggling to remove MapboxCircle

Tags: javascript, dictionary, mapbox

I am struggling to remove a circle marker on the map. This is how I initialize a circle on the map

```
var myCircle = new MapboxCircle({lat: 39.984, lng: -75.343}, 25000, {
    editable: true,
    minRadius: 1500,
    fillColor: '#29AB87'
}).addTo(this.map);
```

but when i run `mycircle.remove()` it throwing the error.

The following is the error I get:

> main.js:1238 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of
> undefined   at MapboxCircle.remove (main.js:1238)   at eval (eval at
>  (main.js:1), :1:13)   at r.
> (index.component.ts:440)   at
> r.push../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js.kt.fire
> (mapbox-gl.js:29)   at r._render (mapbox-gl.js:33)   at
> mapbox-gl.js:33   at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)   at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
> (zone-evergreen.js:390)   at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)

Comment: this is the error :
main.js:1238 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of undefined
    at MapboxCircle.remove (main.js:1238)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main.js:1), <anonymous>:1:13)
    at r.<anonymous> (index.component.ts:440)
    at r.push../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js.kt.fire (mapbox-gl.js:29)
    at r._render (mapbox-gl.js:33)
    at mapbox-gl.js:33
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)

Comment: This seems like an issue with the `mapbox-gl-circle` package version that you might be using in your code.
I tried reproducing the issue and was able to successfully delete the circle using `myCircle.remove()`.
Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pmv8wi